# Filter the data by using For-Loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python. I want to ask a very basic question. I have an excel file which contain mutual fund data, one column contains so many codes (fund codes). I have filtered the data by using that code separately, now I want to apply that filter by using For Loop so that I can calculate the limits for the selected fund at once.

The code for filter is as follow:

Filter_Fund = Data['FundCode'] == 16
16 is the fund code

Appreciate your response.

Comment: `mylist = [x for x in Data if x['FundCode'] == 16]` try this?

Comment: Thanks for your response. please advice how can I put a loop instead of that 16

Comment: Sent you an email.